# Product between three data frames based on condition in one

Tags: r, dataframe

I have three data frames. The examples provided here are simplified and are very different from the original data I am working with.

I have defined three dataframes as follows:

```
mata <- data.frame(matrix (data = c(1.5,2.1, 3.3, 4.5, 5.1, 6.5), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=T))
matb <- data.frame(matrix (data = c(4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=T))
matc <- data.frame(matrix (data = c(8,6, 9, 7 , 4, 3), nrow = 3, ncol=2, byrow = T))
```

The data look like following:

```
> mata
   X1  X2
1 1.5 2.1
2 3.3 4.5
3 5.1 6.5
> matb
  X1 X2
1  4  5
2  6  7
3  8  9
> matc
  X1 X2
1  8  6
2  9  7
3  4  3
```

Now, I want to calculate the product of `mata` , `matb` , and `matc` depending on the condition used in `mata`.

I want to first check if the values in `mata` fall between 0 and 30. Then I want to calculate a new matrix Q(0) , Q(1) .... Q(30) where Q = mata*matb * matc

For each row I want to find Q(0) to Q(30). When I am referring Q(0) then I am looking at all the values greater than 0 and so on.

**My approach:**
I created a logical matrix to check whether the values in `mata` fall on the specified range.

For example I want to find the values greater than 2 and then find the product.

```
check1 <- sapply(mata, function(x) x>2)


> check1
        X1   X2
[1,] FALSE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE
[3,]  TRUE TRUE
```

The matrix check1 found the exact spots which I am interested in. Now, I want to find the product by row for values greater than 2 in `mata`. I may eventually need to use `rowSums` to get only one value but not sure how to implement here.

I used the following code:

```
> mata[check1] * matb[check1] * matc[check1]
[1] 178.2 163.2  63.0 220.5 175.5
```

What I want is when the value is false, I want to report the product as zero and for the rest I want to calculate using the corresponding values.

**The expected output is as follows when values are greater than 2:**

```
 63
 398.7 
 338.7
```

What is the efficient way to check for values 0 to 30 at once. I think we could use for loop but I am not sure how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: In the example you can just make a single data frame of 6 columns which would simplify the problem by allowing you use an apply function. Does the real data also allow that?

Comment: My real data has 7500 rows and 36 columns for each of the data frames.  I think we could combine all the data frames but would be a huge one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
matA <- mata  #Copy your mata (so mata won't be changed, just the copy)
check1 <- sapply(mata, function(x) x>2)
matA[!check1]<-0 #Replace values that do not check with your criterion by 0
rowSums(matA*matb*matc) #Compute
[1]  63.0 398.7 338.7
```

If you want to try multiple thresholds, you can wrap it into a function and apply it to your data:

```
f <- function(mata,matb,matc,threshold){
    matA <- mata
    check1 <- sapply(mata, function(x) x>threshold)
    matA[!check1]<-0
    rowSums(matA*matb*matc)
}
sapply(0:30, function(x)f(mata,matb,matc,x))
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31]
[1,] 111.0 111.0  63.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,] 398.7 398.7 398.7 398.7 220.5   0.0   0.0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,] 338.7 338.7 338.7 338.7 338.7 338.7 175.5    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: +1 Wow, what an awesome piece of code. Thank you so much. The function will really help in my real data also.

Comment: @Jdbaba you're welcome. You were almost there, just an exclamation point away from the solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(mata,matb,matc))
df2 <- apply(df,1,function(x) {
  a <- ifelse(x[1] > 2, (x[1]*x[3]*x[5]),0)
  b <- ifelse(x[2] > 2, (x[2]*x[4]*x[6]),0)
  return(a+b)
})
```

edit: Using something resembling the real data

```
df <- data.frame(matrix (data = runif(810000,0,5), nrow = 7500, ncol=108, byrow = T))
df2 <- apply(df,1,function(x) {
  a <- sapply(seq(1,35,by=2),function(y) {
    ifelse(x[y] > 2, (x[y]*x[y+36]*x[y+72]),0)
  })
  b <- sapply(seq(2,36,by=2),function(y) {
    ifelse(x[y] > 2, (x[y]*x[y+36]*x[y+72]),0)
  })
  return(a+b)
})
```

Comment: This will work for this small dataset but using this on a large dataset will be difficult I think.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for this solution. It looks more general now and can be used.